# Nltk on mac osx 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-snow-leopard, nltk

I'm having issues using nltk on my Mac Os 10.6.8.
I've installed Setuputools, Pip, Numpy, PyYAML and NLTK as it's said in nltk codumentation (http://nltk.org/install.html) but i sitll get this error while trying to import nltk in python:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from collocations import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.util import ingrams
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "tokenize.py", line 13, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Python using is

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But if I do a double tab on pythons shows that I do have this installed

```
pydoc             python-config     python2.6-config  pythonw2-32
pydoc2            python2           python2.7         pythonw2.5
pydoc2.5          python2-32        python2.7-32      pythonw2.6
pydoc2.6          python2-config    python2.7-config  pythonw2.7
pydoc2.7          python2.5         pythonw           pythonw2.7-32
python            python2.5-config  pythonw-32        
python-32         python2.6         pythonw2
```

If i try installing again it's says that all it's good and if i try doing it with `pip install nltk`says

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML>=3.09 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nltk)
Cleaning up...
```

I'm working on a school project that I need to turn in in these days so your help would really, reallly, really be apreciated!
Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Are you running the interpreter from a directory containing a file effectively named `tokenize.py`? If so, change you working directory, and try again.

Comment: thanks @doukremt I just saw the response! I managed to work it installing another version :)

Comment: Haha, 6 months later!

Comment: @doukremt I fixed 5 months ago but I forgot to check out here XD